# Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c Host Name

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

I want to install oracle enterprise manager on win7 on virtualbox.I have run installation when on the 5. step there requires middleware home location,agent base directory and Host name.The host name default came "10.0.2.15" but when i click next "Host Name: You cannot enter an IP address(10.0.2.15) in place of host name. Enter a valid host name". So what should i write host name area?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Hostname and IPs to local DNS Resolver i.e. (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)

For Detail Pls visit.
http://ahmermansoor.blogspot.com/2016/02/oem-cloud-control-12c-part2.html

Answer (score 0):

You should enter a fully qualified domain name, not an IP address.

This setting is documented in the [Enterprise Manager Cloud Control Basic Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/install_em_exist_db.htm#EMBSC166):

> The host name must resolve to the local host or virtual host because the host name is used for the local Oracle WebLogic Server as well as the Oracle Management Service. Do not provide a remote host or a load balancer virtual host in this field. Do not enter an IP address. Do not use underscores in the name. Short names are allowed, but you will see a warning, so Oracle recommends that you enter a fully qualified domain name instead.